# Swift: return Array of type self

Tags: ios, arrays, types, swift

I would like to write a class function, which will return an array of the class type. As far as I understood, I can use `Self` for the `objective-c instanceType`. My goal is to create an `extension` for a `NSManagedObject` with a `fetchObjects` method. This method will than return an array of `NSManagedObject` subclasses. Here is a example of my pseudo code which does not compile:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func fetchObjects(entity: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext, predicate: NSPredicate?, sortDescriptors: NSSortDescriptor[]?) -> Self[] {
        // can't define return type of an array with type Self
        // also var declaration does not work
        var objects : Self[]?

        return objects
    }
}
```

Any idea how i can define an array of type Self?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can parameterize the function like so: `class fund fetchObjects<Self>(...) -> Self[]?` but I don't think you can genericize the bridging from ObjC to Swift, such that the compiler can guarantee that for every NSManagedObject there is going to be a corresponding Swift object. That would be awesome though, great question.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not looking for an array of 'subclasses', you are looking for an array of instances with types that are a subclass of a named superclass?

Comment: Yes thats what i want to achieve, so if i would call it on a NSManagedObject subclass and it will return an array of instances of this subclass

Comment: But if i declare <Self>, isn't it used as a generic, as if i would write class fund fetchObjects<T>? Or is it the the current class type?

Answer (score 9):

This is the jist of what I use for a similar function, note that it's an extension on `NSManagedObjectContext` rather than `NSManagedObject`.  Something similar could probably be done on `NSManagedObject`

```
protocol NamedManagedObject {

    class func entityName() -> String;

}

extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    func fetchObjects<T:NSManagedObject where T:NamedManagedObject>(entity:T.Type, predicate:NSPredicate? = nil, sortDescriptors:NSSortDescriptor[]? = nil) -> T[]? {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity.entityName())

        request.predicate = predicate
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

        var error:NSError? = nil
        let results = self.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as? T[]

        assert(error == nil)

        return results
    }

}

extension MyObjectClass : NamedManagedObject {
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "MyObjectClass"
    }
}
```

Then using it is as simple as:

```
let objects = managedObjectContext.fetchObjects(MyObjectClass)
```

Note that you can also implement NamedManagedObject for all NSManagedObjects with:

```
extension NSManagedObject : NamedManagedObject {
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)
    }
}
```

If you also insure that all your classes are explicitly given Objective-C friendly names:

```
@objc(MyManagedObject)
class MyManagedObject : NSManagedObject { ... }
```

Comment: Great! the ".Type" thing is what i looked for too. Actually wanted to do the same as you first ;)