# Swift - Generic methods

Tags: generics, swift

In java you could have a generic method similar to below, where the type is explicitly specified and passed to the method as an argument. Is this possible with swift?

```
public T fetchObject(Class<T> clazz, int id) {
   // My table name is the same as class name
   // So based on the generic type passed to method I want to fetch that record.
}

User user = fetchObject(User.class, 5);
```

What I'm trying to achieve

```
public func fetchObject (id: Int /* Somehow pass the type */) -> T? {
   // I need a way to know what class type has to be used with this generic method
   // Create NSEntityDescription based on the generic class passed
   // managedObjectContext getExistingObjectById
}
```

Comment: -1? How about a comment?

Comment: @Zaph I did, and I already know how to write generic functions in swift. This is a special case where you also pass the class type

Comment: Yeah, the drive-by down votes without a reason are not helpful and rather weasel like.

Comment: Is your question specifically for subclasses of NSManagedObject? Then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834753/using-swift-protocols-with-generics or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537238/swift-return-array-of-type-self might help.

Comment: @MartinR It's a question about generis, the ManagedObject part is just to give a context on What I need to achieve using generics, and why. And whether it's event possible with Swift generics or not

Comment: Yes, and the questions/answers that I linked to are also about generic functions, and both demonstrate how to pass a type into the function.

Comment: if you want to see more details on generic methods see this Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571293/3992606

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`T.Type` is what I had to use, even better than how java handles this

```
public func fetchObject<T> (id: Int, type: T.Type) -> T? {

}
```

Usage

```
var myClass = fetchObject(5, MyClass.self)
```

Comment: Wouldn't a set of overloads better in this case? E.g.: `func fetchObject(id: Int, type: User.Type) -> User`, or even better: `func fetchUser(id: Int) -> User` ?

Comment: This was just an example I provided to explain the problem. What I'm actually trying to achieve is a method that takes a dictionary and a class type, then based on key/values it creates and populate an NSManagedObject and saves the context

Comment: Then, why not a Dictionary of Keys/Closures? Could possibly end up much more elegant, too.

Comment: I want it to be automated, I have control over what the API sends, and as long as key/values match between server/client, I don't have to write the code over and over every time I add a new model. I want everything automated through a single generic method

Comment: I did it a while back in Objective C https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper, which due to the nature of Objective C is not type safe. Now with swift I'm trying to rewrite this library to be typesafe