# Generic on class that is subclassed

Tags: ios, swift

In my application written in Swift, I have the following class structure. Class A has a static method which does some stuff, but in a very simple form it looks like the code below.

```
class A {
    class func create<T: A>() -> T? {
        println(NSStringFromClass(T));
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Class `B` is subclassed from class `A`.

```
class B : A {
}
```

Now, when I execute the following code, the println command outputs `A` instead of `B`.

```
var myVar:B? = B.create();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I would expect it to output `B`.

When debugging and putting a breakpoint in the `create` method, the value `$swift.type.T`    is defined as a `Builtin.RawPointer MyApp.A` instead of `B`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, I get "MyApp.B" as output.

Answer (score 1):

Your generic class method on `A` doesn't make sense to me. Instead I would actually use something like the code below. This way it creates an instance of `Self`, which is whatever class you call it on. No need for generics in this case.

```
class A {
    required init() {}
    class func create() -> Self {
        return self()
    }
    func test() -> String {
        return "A"
    }
}
class B : A {
    override func test() -> String {
        return "B"
    }
}

let b = B.create() // "{A}" according to the playground, but it is a "B" instance!
b.test() // "B"
```

Please note that `A` needs a required initializer because the use of `Self`. When doing it in playground, the created instance is shown as `{A}` on the right. This is an error in Xcode I believe, the actual type is correct.

**Edit:**

I believe the code above isn't what you were looking for exactly, now I do get what you're trying to do. I would suggest not doing that by depending on the actual class name, but using a generic class to create the instances for you:

```
protocol Entity {
    init()
    class func entityName() -> String
}
class EntityFactory<T : Entity> {
    class func newEntity() -> T? {
        var entity: T?
        // ... create entity here using T.entityName()
        return entity
    }
}
class Person : Entity {
    required init() {}
    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Person"
    }
}

let person = EntityFactory<Person>.newEntity()
```

Think this is a more elegant solution, which moves the responsibility of creating an entity to a separate generic class. This results in code that is maintainable and testable. You can even abstract it out further for i.e. unit testing purposes, but that seems a bit out of scope here.

Comment: The static methods is actually a bit more complicated than just returning an clean instance of the class itself. It involves querying CoreData for a record with the type specified, if that doesn't exist it create a CoreData object and returns that.

Comment: @WimHaanstra: If your question is about creating Core Data managed objects then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537238/swift-return-array-of-type-self or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834753/using-swift-protocols-with-generics might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I finally went with the EntityFactory method. This solved it in a really clean way. I did not include the entityName method, because I use NSStringFromClass() method.