# Return as CustomManagedObjectClass NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> at base NSManagedObject class

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, base-class

This is my first `Swift` project also with `CoreData`. `Swift` doesn't have `return instancetype` like in Objective C. 
In `Swift - CoreData` class, I am using common base class for `NSManagedObject`. There I have implemented a `class` function.

```
class func FRCWith(sortArray: [NSSortDescriptor], predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.shared.managedObjectContext) -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> {
    let className = self.nameOfTheClass
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: className)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortArray
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 4

    if let predicateValue = predicate {
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicateValue
    }

    let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> = NSFetchedResultsController.init(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

I want to return `NSFetchedResultsController<customCoreDataClass>` instead of common `NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>`.

```
var schoolvalue: NSFetchedResultsController<SchoolDetails> = SchoolDetails.FRCWith([sort])
var schoolvalue: NSFetchedResultsController<StudentDetails> = StudentDetails.FRCWith([sort], preidcate)
```

Right now I am using in `for loop` like this and checking is that FRC `as! customClass`

```
let loopValue: SchoolDetails = someFRC.object(at: IndexPath.init(row: value, section: 0)) as! SchoolDetails
```

Found some kind of [`solution in StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24538011). That `T` thing, I do not understand that.

Is that possible make a method like that?

### Thanks, @Paulw11 for an answer.

Randomly app crash when init

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<T> = NSFetchedResultsController<T>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

[from below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222983/3589771). 
Because

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>\\ line return nil. There is no crash below iOS 10.x.
```

It only occurs when downloading from App store or Testflight.

Comment: That T thing is Swift generics. They are described in the Swift book from Apple. You are already using generics when you say `NSFetchedResultsController<StudentDetails>`

Comment: Thanks for the info @Paulw11. In that another answer `func fetchObjects<T:NSManagedObject where T:NamedManagedObject>(entity:T.Type, predicate:NSPredicate? = nil, sortDescriptors:NSSortDescriptor[]? = nil) -> T[]?` Is there any way to overcome this `NamedManagedObject` static class as dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift generics for this.  You specify a placeholder, often `T` is used but it doesn't have to be, that "stands in" for the actual class that will be used.  In this case you need to specify that `T` must be a `NSManagedObject` or a subclass of `NSManagedObect`

Declare your function as:

```
class func FRCWith<T: NSManagedObject>(sortArray: [NSSortDescriptor], predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<T> {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortArray
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 4

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<T> =
        NSFetchedResultsController<T>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

Then you can invoke it using:

```
if let frc: NSFetchedResultsController<SchoolDetails> = try? CD.FRCWith(sortArray: [], mainContext: moc) {
    // Do something with results
    if let schoolDetails = frc.fetchedObjects?.first {
        // schoolDetails will be an instance of SchoolDetails
    }
}
```

Note that I have declared the function as `throws` rather than hiding the error inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, Can you share something like this (kind of) document or example. Becuase ` where T:NamedManagedObject` If I delete and tried there is no need for this question.

Comment: Th either answer you linked to is using the `NamedManagedObject` protocol to get the entity. I avoided this by using `T.fetchRequest()` that is now available; `T` already knows it’s own entity, so specifying it explicitly is not required.

Comment: `let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>` this line return nil and checked all coredata class have `@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<name> {
        return NSFetchRequest<name>(entityName: "name")
    }`. Do you know what's the problem?. Also app support iOS 9.x added available ios version for greater and lesser there is no crash in lesser than iOS 10.

Comment: It doesn't happen every time @Paulw11, only when downloading from App store or Testflight, So, it takes time to find this issue.